# How to convert string date into timestamp in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date string like `'06/21/2021 9:27 AM'`, and I want to convert it into timestamp type in pyspark.
I have tried this approach, along with others, and it always seems to return null.

```py
df = df.select(
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date_string', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')).cast(TimestampType())
)
```

Has anyone successfully converted this string format into a timestamp format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`06/21/2021 9:27 AM` doesn't contain the second-of-minute value so you should remove the `:ss` in the parser format, see this example:

```
spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('06/21/2021 9:27 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a')) ts").show()

+-------------------+
|                 ts|
+-------------------+
|2021-06-21 09:27:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use DataFrame APIs with `withColumn` and [`to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html) function, but before we need to set the `timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

df.withColumn('ts', F.to_timestamp('date_string', format='MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'))
```

---

#### Example

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('06/21/2021 9:27 AM', ),
  ('06/11/2021 9:02 PM', ),
  ('01/28/2021 12:56 AM', )
], ('date_string', ))

df = df.withColumn('ts', F.to_timestamp('date_string', format='MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a'))

df.show()

+-------------------+-------------------+
|        date_string|                 ts|
+-------------------+-------------------+
| 06/21/2021 9:27 AM|2021-06-21 09:27:00|
| 06/11/2021 9:02 PM|2021-06-11 21:02:00|
|01/28/2021 12:56 AM|2021-01-28 00:56:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```